# Continuity question on topological product space

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let $\left\{X_a \right\}_{a \in I}$ be an indexed family of topological spaces. Consider their topological product $X=\prod_{a \in I} X_a$. Let $I'$ be a finite subset of $I$ and define $X' =\prod_{a \in I'} X_a$. Let $y$ be a point of $X$. Define an embedding $j:X' \rightarrow X$ by $j(x')(a)=x'(a)$ if $a \in I'$ and $j(x')(a)=y(a)$ if $a \in I-I'$, where $x' \in X'$. Let $p_a : X \rightarrow X_a$ be the projection on the $a$ factor $x \mapsto x(a)$.

I read the statement "j is continuous, since all maps $p_a j$ are continuous". I can see that $p_a j$ is continuous for any $a \in I$. But why does this continuity imply the continuity of $j$?

Comment: What is your definition of topological product?

Comment: The topology consists of unions of sets of the form $p_{a_1}^{-1}(O_{a_1}) \cap \cdots \cap p_{a_k}^{-1}(O_{a_k})$, where $O_{a_i}$ is open in $X_{a_i}$ and $p_a$ is the projection onto the $a$ factor.

Comment: I see it now :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a special case of a general result that's worth knowing:

> **Theorem:** Let $X=\prod\limits_{i\in I}X_i$ be a product of topological spaces, and for $i\in I$ let $p_i:X\to X_i$ be the canonical projection map. Let $Y$ be a topological space, and let $f:Y\to X$ be any function. Then $f$ is continuous iff $p_i\circ f:Y\to X_i$ is continuous for each $i\in I$.

Clearly continuity of $f$ implies continuity of the compositions $p_i\circ f$, since the composition of continuous functions is continuous. The converse implication is an easy consequence of the fact that the sets of the form

$$\bigcap_{i\in F}p_i^{-1}[U_i]\;,$$ where $F$ is a finite subset of $I$, and $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ for each $i\in F$, are a base for the product topology.

Comment: You have assumed $F$ is finite while the theorem you mentioned does not state any assumptions regarding the cardinality of the index set $I$. I came across the same theorem, thought of the exact same proof, but I am not sure that the result is true if $I$ is countably infinite. I feel that the sets of the form $\cap_{i \in I} p_i^{-1}[U_i]$ form a basis even if $I$ were not finite, but I need clarification about that.

Comment: @TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr: No, those sets are not a base for the product topology when $I$ is infinite (except in the very special case in which only finitely many of the spaces $X_i$ have more than one point); they are a base for the [*box topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology), which in general is strictly finer than the product topology when $I$ is infinite and is much less well behaved.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So how is the theorem proved for the case when $I$ is infinite? Are you saying that any open set of the product space has to be union of sets of the form $\cap_{i \in F}p_i^{-1}[U_i]$ where $F$ is finite subset of $I$? That way, taking inverse on the basis will result in open sets of $X$. Please confirm.

Comment: I checked in https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~megereli/semin-Gili11.pdf and https://math.mit.edu/~jhirsh/terilla_subspace_quotient.pdf and I realized that I missed a crucial point. The topology on $X$ is actually defined to be the ones generated by the basis that you have mentioned namely $\cap_{i \in F}p_i^{-1}[U_i]$ where $F$ is a finite subset of $I$. You did mention that in your answer but I thought it was a theorem, not a definition. But it is indeed the definition of the topology on $X$ which then makes the rest of the proof fairly obvious. Please do confirm if I am thinking correctly.

Comment: @TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. FWIW, I wanna mention the reason why this was not clear to me. I am studying Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology." In the definition 7.6 of Chapter 3 (Topological spaces), where he defines product space on an arbitrary family of topologies, he does not explicitly mention the finite nature of the set $F$ and you have to infer that based on the way he has defined the product space. After reading from other sources and your answer, this point became clear to me.

Comment: @TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr: You’re very welcome; I’m glad that you got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Since each $p_a j$ is continuous, this means that for each $a$ and each open $U \subset X_a$, we have $j^{-1}(p_a^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X'$.  Now note that the collection of sets of the form $p_a^{-1}(U)$ generate the topology of $X$ (just by definition of the product topology).